# Is there a proper way to append JSON Data to a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to add data that I am reading from a series of JSON files to a Numpy array (or whatever data collection would work best). My idea, is that I want to sort a collection of episodes of a tv show by episode title.

The problem I have encountered, is actually creating the collection from the data.

The intent, is that I want to be able to have a collection of the items found within the for loop [a,b,c,d]; for each episode of the show.

Is a Numpy array the best way to go about making this collection, or should I use something else?

```
season1 = open('THEJSONFILES\seasonone.json', 'r')

season_array = np.array(['episodeTitle','seasonNum', 'episodeNum', 'plotContents'])
    
def ReadTheDarnJsonFile(jsonTitle):

    seasondata = jsonTitle.read()
    seasonobj = j.loads(seasondata)
    
    list = (seasonobj['episodes'])
    
    for i in range(len(list)):
        a = str(list[i].get('title'))
        b = str(list[i].get('seasonNumber'))
        c = str(list[i].get('episodeNumber'))
        d = str(list[i].get('plot')) 
        print(a, b, c, d)
        print("----------------")
        # np.append(season_array, [a,b,c,d]) this is not correct

ReadTheDarnJsonFile(season1)
print(season_array)
```

Comment: `numpy` is a pretty heavy dependency that's good for numerical analysis; is there any reason why you think `numpy` arrays are preferrable to vanilla Python lists for this task?

Comment: It was a force of habit from college. What would you recommend? Could you make a list of objects containing those 4 variables, for each episode(index) with lists?

Comment: Could you provide some debugging details? What is the input / JSON file data, what is the output of your script, and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: JSON is a string or file, which when loaded gives a nesting of lists and dict with numbers and strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.

```
import json as j
import pandas as pd

emptyArray = []

season1 = open('THEJSONFILES\seasonone.json', 'r')
season2 = open('THEJSONFILES\seasontwo.json', 'r')
season3 = open('THEJSONFILES\seasonthree.json', 'r')
season4 = open('THEJSONFILES\seasonfour.json', 'r')
season5 = open('THEJSONFILES\seasonfive.json', 'r')
season6 = open('THEJSONFILES\seasonsix.json', 'r')
season7 = open('THEJSONFILES\seasonseven.json', 'r')

columnData = ["episodeTitle", "seasonIndex", "episodeIndex", "plot", "imageURL"]
    

finalDf = pd.DataFrame

def ReadTheDarnJsonFile(jsonTitle):

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columnData)     

    seasonData = jsonTitle.read()
    seasonObj = j.loads(seasonData)
    
    currentSeasonList = (seasonObj['episodes'])
    
    for i in range(len(currentSeasonList)):
        tempTitle = str(currentSeasonList[i].get('title'))
        tempSN = str(currentSeasonList[i].get('seasonNumber'))
        tempEN = str(currentSeasonList[i].get('episodeNumber'))
        tempPlot = str(currentSeasonList[i].get('plot'))
        tempImage = str(currentSeasonList[i].get('image'))
      
        dataObj = pd.Series([tempTitle, tempSN, tempEN, tempPlot, tempImage], index=(df.columns))
        df.loc[i] = dataObj
        
    emptyArray.append(df)
    
ReadTheDarnJsonFile(season1)
ReadTheDarnJsonFile(season2)
ReadTheDarnJsonFile(season3)
ReadTheDarnJsonFile(season4)
ReadTheDarnJsonFile(season5)
ReadTheDarnJsonFile(season6)
ReadTheDarnJsonFile(season7)

finalDf = pd.concat(emptyArray)
print(emptyArray)


holyOutput = finalDf.sort_values(by=['episodeTitle'])
holyOutput.reset_index(inplace=True)
holyOutput.to_json("P:\\ProjectForStarWarsCloneWarsJson\JSON\OutputJsonV2.json")
```

Answer (score 1):

2 notes. First I would avoid using `list` as a variable name because it is a keyword in python. Second I would recommend using a custom class for your data for maximum readability.

```
season1 = open('THEJSONFILES\seasonone.json', 'r')

season_array = np.array(['episodeTitle','seasonNum', 'episodeNum', 'plotContents'])


class episode:
    def __init__(self,title,seasonNumber,episodeNumber,plot):
        self.title = title
        self.seasonNumber = seasonNumber
        self.episodeNumber = episodeNumber
        self.plot = plot
    def summary(self):
        print("Season "+str(self.seasonNumber)+" Episode "+str(self.episodeNumber))
        print(self.title)
        print(self.plot)

def ReadTheDarnJsonFile(jsonTitle):

    seasondata = jsonTitle.read()
    seasonobj = j.loads(seasondata)
    
    episodes = (seasonobj['episodes'])
    season_array = []

    for i in range(len(episodes)):
        a = str(list[i].get('title'))
        b = str(list[i].get('seasonNumber'))
        c = str(list[i].get('episodeNumber'))
        d = str(list[i].get('plot'))
        season_array.append(episode(a,b,c,d)) this is not correct
    return season_array

season_array = Read

TheDarnJsonFile(season1)
for item in season_array:
    item.summary()
```